# How to retrieve page content from a list of website links using a for loop in python and lxml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I am scraping data from a website and I have retrieved a list of URLs from which I will be getting the final data I need. How do I retrieve the html from this list of addresses using a loop?

Using xpath in lxml I have a list of URLs. Now I need to retrieve page content for each of thse URLs and then get use xpath once again to get the final data from each of these pages. I am able to individually get data from each page if use

```
pagecontent=requests.get(linklist[1])
```

then I am able to get the content of 1 url but if I use a for loop

```
for i in range(0,8):
    pagecontent[i]=requests.get(linklist[i])
```

I get an error list assignment index out of range. I have also tried using

```
pagecontent=[requests.get(linklist) for s in linklist]
```

the error I see is No connection adapters were found for '['http...(list of links)...]'

I am trying to get a list pagecontent where each item in the list has html of the respective URLs. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking to name each `pagecontent` with the number of the related request - for example, the content received in the 3rd `requests.get` will be called `pagecontent_3` or something like that?

Comment: @JackFleeting I am trying to just call it pagecontent[3], so basically it will be an element in the list. If that is even possible. I do not want to manually write a new name every time because I am working with a variable number of pages even though for current purpose it is 9. I don't have a lot of experience with python, mostly C and I haven't created variable names within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of your comment, I believe this (or something like this) may be what you're looking for; I can't try it myself since I don't have your `linklist`, but you should be able to modify the code to fit your situation. It uses [python f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to accomplish what you need.

```
linklist = ['www.example_1.com','www.example_2.com','www.example_3.com']
pages = {} #initialize an empty dictionary to house your name/link entries

for i in range(len(linklist)):      
      pages[f'pagecontent[{i+1}]'] = linklist[i] #the '+1' is needed because python counts from 0...
for name, link in pages.items() :
    print (name, link)
```

Output:

```
pagecontent[1] www.example_1.com
pagecontent[2] www.example_2.com
pagecontent[3] www.example_3.com
```